# Running common "alter table" command on mysql returns "no database selected" error

Tags: mysql, wordpress, alter

I'm trying to fix some Wordpress character encoding problems by going through and altering all tables to use utf8. But the command I'm using doesn't work.

The command:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

The error:

> ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected

This seems to work for everyone. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to specify the database that contains the table you are altering.  you can do this in two ways:

1)

run this command before your alter table commang:

```
USE `database_name`;
ALTER TABLE `tbl_name` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

or 2)

```
ALTER TABLE `database_name`.`tbl_name` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: Thanks Tucker. So simple—that's probably why I couldn't find another topic on it.